# Mensa question number 30: progressive matrix of line shapes

Tags: visual, pattern, progressive-matrix

[image]

Mensa question number 30 .. In the question I think there is some diagonal thing.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! If this isn't a puzzle you created yourself, then you need to provide a link back to the original source.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it should be

> D

because

> the given matrix is a combination of two much simpler matrices:
>
> [image]

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our [attribution policy](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide); that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism.